# How to sum values printed by print() in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, printing, return

```
T <- function (p,q) {
for (x in 1:3) {
for (y in 1:3) {
sum(p*x + q*y)
print(sum(p*x + q*y))
}
}
}

sum(T(2,2))
```

I want the sum of 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 10, 8, 10, 12 which is the output of the loop where p=2 and q=2 but the result is

```
sum(T(2,2))
[1] 4
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 6
[1] 8
[1] 10
[1] 8
[1] 10
[1] 12
```

Is there any way that I can get the sum or change the printed value to a vector rather than a list of each value? sum() function doesn't work on printed value.

Comment: You can create a vector object and assign the output to it and then do the sum. i.e. `T <- function (p,q) {
v1 <- c();
for (x in 1:3) {
for (y in 1:3) {
v1 <- c(v1,p*x + q*y);
}
}
;sum(v1);
}; T(2, 2)`

Comment: Vectorize: `T <- function(p, q){sum(outer(p * 1:3, q * 1:3, \`+\`))}`

Answer (score 0):

Printing to the screen does exactly that; it doesn't return the value printed to the calling code. Your function needs to build a vector and return that. Here's a few different ways of doing it:

#### Code along the lines of what you were trying to do, but starting with an empty numeric vector and building it for each iteration:

```
T1 <- function(p, q) {
  out <- numeric(0)
  for (x in 1:3) {
    for (y in 1:3) {
      out <- c(out, p * x + q * y)
    }
  }
  out
}
```

#### Preassigning the vector size and assigning to specific members of the vector

```
T2 <- function(p, q) {
  out <- numeric(3 ^ 2)
  for (x in 1:3) {
    for (y in 1:3) {
      out[(x - 1) * 3 + y] <- p * x + q * y
    }
  }
  out
}
```

#### Using one of the map functions in `purrr` (overkill here but can be extended to functions which don't easily vectorise)

```
library(purrr)
T3 <- function(p, q) {
  map2_dbl(rep(1:3, each = 3), rep(1:3, 3), function(x, y) p * x + q * y)
}
```

#### Using vector arithmetic to return the result in one command

```
T4 <- function(p, q) {
  rep(1:3, each = 3) * p + rep(1:3, 3) * q
}
```

#### Using `outer` to achieve the same as T4 (as per @alistaire's comment):

```
T5 <- function(p, q) {
  c(outer(1:3 * p, 1:3 * q, `+`))
}
```

It should be noted that the efficiency of these method will vary as the size of the loops increases, but that in general method 4 will be the most efficient closely followed by method 5. For small loops, interestingly method 1 seems to be better than 2, but 1 becomes inefficient as the loop size increases because R has to move memory around to keep increasing the size of the vector.